how do i resolve this problem with upgrading my helm
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "prometheus-server" namespace: "monitoring" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
I am trying to upgrade my helm on my AWS EKS cluster V1.26.13 but it is falling with the following error message after executing this command:
helm -n monitoring upgrade prometheus  prometheus-community/prometheus -f development/monitoring/prometheus//values.yaml --dry-run
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "prometheus-server" namespace: "monitoring" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"

You need to change the apiVersion: on your PodDisruptionBudget to policy/v1; in Kubernetes 1.26 the beta version goes away.  You need to do this before you upgrade your cluster.  It sounds like you're running a third-party Helm chart, so you'd have to ask the maintainers of that chart to take this update.

@DavidMaze Thank you for the input. But my PodDisruptionBudget is 'policy/v1' I do not understand why my helm is still pointing to the beta version.

The error message says "from current release manifest" – what Helm believes is currently installed in the cluster is the beta version.  You need to make sure your installed charts aren't using deprecated API versions before you run the cluster upgrade.
